# Array that points to another array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm new to C.

Create an array which holds at every index a pointer to another array of dynamic size.

```
int main()
{
  unsigned int i , j;

  int* array1[2];
  int a1[] = {1,2,3};
  int a2[] = {2,3};

  array1[0] = a1;
  array1[1] = a2;

  for (i=0 ; i < 2; i++) {
     printf(" the value of array1[%d] = %d" , i , *array1[i]);
  }

  return 1;
}
```

> the value of array1[0] = 1
>
> the value of array1[1] = 2

Only first elements are getting printed . How to print the whole array the index points to. What thing i'm missing.

EDITED ::
I now understand the use but similarly doing it directly , causing an array.

```
`unsigned int* c[3];
 c[0] = {0, 5, 4, 7};  //  This Line Err` 
 c[1] = {0, 5, 4, 3, 2, 6, 7};
 c[2] = {0, 5, 4, 3, 2};
```

> Causing an error : file try.c line xx function main: syntax error before `{'

Why ??

Thanks

Comment: This isn't how to create arrays of dynamic size. The task proposed probably wants you to allocate memory with the memory management functions.

Comment: %d prints an integer, it will not print a whole array. `*array1[i]` accesses the first element of the array, the same as `array1[i][0]`.

Comment: One follow up : Similarly doing it directly.  unsigned int* c[3];

     c[0] = {0, 5, 4, 7}; causing an error : file try.c line 48 function main: syntax error before `{'
Why ???

Answer (score 2):

As you know, **array1[0]** holds a pointer to the first element of a1 array; to print all elements of `a1` array, you should iterate over it, something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    printf(" the value of a1[%d] = %d", i, *(array1[0] + i);
}
```

Comment: Ok, you can initialize another for over the first index and print two arrays! I just address the problem.

Comment: `*(array1[0] + i)` is equivalent to writing `array1[0][i]`.

Comment: Yes two nested for loops.

Comment: But be mindful that you need to capture the number of elements that each array holds. You will not be able to rely on the `sizeof` operator *outside* of the scope where the arrays *pointed to* were declared.

Answer (score 1):

An array is decayed to a pointer in C, in particular when passing it as argument (or storing it in a pointer).

What you are missing is that at runtime, the actual size of the array is *not* kept (and `sizeof` is a *compile-time* operator, replaced by the compiler by a constant - except for [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)s).

You might wish to keep the array size and its content together. Using a `struct` with a last [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) is a cute way to do that:

```
struct vect_st { unsigned size; int flexarr[]; };
struct vect_st* arr1[2];
```

Such structures need to be [heap allocated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) (because you know their real size only at runtime):

```
arr1[0] = malloc(sizeof(struct (vect_st) + 2*sizeof(int));
if (!arr1[0]) {perror("malloc arr1[0]"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
arr1[0]->size = 2;
arr1[0]->flexarr[0] = 4;
arr1[0]->flexarr[1] = 17;
arr1[1] = malloc(sizeof(struct (vect_st) + 3*sizeof(int));
if (!arr1[1]) {perror("malloc arr1[1]"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
arr1[1]->size = 3;
arr1[1]->flexarr[0] = 5;
arr1[1]->flexarr[1] = 6;
arr1[1]->flexarr[2] = 7;
```

OF course, you should release the memory when you don't need it, so you'll probably end your `main` with code like

```
free(arr1[0]), arr1[0] = NULL;
free(arr1[1]), arr1[1] = NULL;
```

Beware of [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak), [buffer overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) and other [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). So compile your code with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and the [`gdb` debugger](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/).

Notice also that you should usually not declare non-small arrays (or aggregates) as local data (e.g. some *local* `int biglocarr[1000000];` inside your `main` or some other function), since the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) is limited in size (typically to a few megabytes, so no more than a few hundred bytes per call frame). Read about [stack overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) and avoid them.

Comment: Notice that I wrote something wrong in my first edition of that answer. Flexible array members need to belong to heap allocated data.

Answer (score 0):

You are using *array1[i] , here " * " means pointer and value at array1[i] and i is 0 in first case, so it is pointing to a1 base, i.e. 1 and so on..